# Jenkins: block scm polling when upstream projects are building

Tags: jenkins, version-control

I was looking for the answer a few days, but haven't found an easy solution.

All the projects are related to each other by upstream and downstream triggers. In all projects set the same interval poll SCM. After the launch of the first project, the second project will start, then the third and so on. And when in the middle of the chain SCM timer triggers on any project, it begins to build of this project. There is an option to block the project until the upstream projects are building. But!!! The problem is that the CMS trigger still adds a job to the queue. I need it isn't add downstream jobs to the queue and do not do anything, if upstream projects are building. In other words, I need upstream job freezing SCM triggers in all downstream projects.

I know about pipeline, but I'm looking for something simpler. Thanks.

Comment: If the projects are related to each other by triggers, do they also need to poll the SCM? Can you not have one (or more) entry points which poll SCM and tthen trigger the downstream jobs?

Comment: No, sometimes upstream job can trigger downstream job, if the upstream job was changes. And sometimes not. But downstream job can have git changes too and it needs to check too. Therefore I need SCM polling in all projects to check new changes, but if the upstream project has changes, builds and triggers downstream projects, I would like SCM polling logic by interval of downstream projects has been turn off at the same time.

Comment: Why not just check which module changed and trigger the relevant section of your build? Which SCM you're using?